# How can I verify that .net 4.0 FULL profile is installed?

Tags: .net

On startup of our app we need to check that the .net FULL profile is installed. If someone has just the client profile installed, parts of our app will not work.

How can we test that the full profile is installed?

Comment: Have you actually tested this or do you just assume it is a problem?  The CLR detects this automatically and [offers to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant I thought so too but we had a case today where they had the client profile installed and the effect was an exception thrown when we tried to use a class that is not in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) yet? There is a way you can query the users registry, and check if they have the full or the client installed, and at what version.