# Setup Project asks for installing .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: windows-installer, installation

My Application uses WCF. I can keep .Net Framework as minimum as 3.5 and it should be supported on Windows 7, 8 and 8.1

**Problem**

I am using Setup Project for deploying my Application. Setting .NET Framework 3.5 in 'Launch Conditions' works fine on Windows 7 and 8.1 but asks for installing .NET Framework 3.5 to continue installation. This happens though Windows 8 has .NET Framework 4.0 installed.
When I change the version to 'Any' throws an error during installation on Win 8, saying: "Error 1001 InstallUtilLib.dll. unknown error".

**Question**

How can a setup project check for a version higher than .NET Framework 3.5 instead of 'Any' and if I have to use 'Any' how to get it working under Win 8?

Comment: Your assumption that it "should be supported" is just wrong.  Windows 8.x doesn't have .NET 3.5 installed by default, it has 4.5.  The user has to explicitly install 3.5 first.  It is also a different flavor of 3.5 that works on 8.x so including an installer for it yourself is not feasible.  Just target 4.0 as the "minimum version" and remove the prerequisite and these problems go away.  If necessary, your program will automatically [trigger the install](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034).

Comment: Another option is to create an installer that installs .NET 3.5 automatically for you, on Win 8.1. Advanced Installer can do this (disclaimer: I work on its development) http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/windows-features.html

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your explanation.