# runing VB.Net projects on other computers (.net framework required)

Tags: .net, vb.net, frameworks

well basically i'm not asking for a way to run vb.net applications without .net framework or similar. but i'm just asking for ideas or advices about what i can do to make it simpler for the user to run my programs ,because each way the user tries to run it without framework it's gonna ask him to download it what makes it more annoying
- i know there is a simple and available way to include .net framework in your setup , or if i don't like to make a setup just a bunch of code , but my programs are not really that important , i mean for example downloading a 200Mb file that just changes one or two registry keys isn't a choice at all

actually vista and win7 comes with .NET 4.0 pre installed so should i just continue without thinking of this problem or there is something i can do about it ?

**note** : VB 6.0 isn't a choice :D

**edit** : to make the question more clear , i'm using visual studio 2008  , is it ok (**ok** means are my programs gonna work on other computers without problems i don't care about advantages.) or should i move to earlier versions ?

Comment: A .NET program knows how to [install .NET all by itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034).  You'll need to document a **real** problem, one you actually observed.  And provide the details.

Comment: i surely know that running a .net program on a computer without .net framework tells you about the problem and allows you to download and install the framework by itself , i'm just wondering if there is anything i should be aware of according to this !

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't actually come with Framework 4 installed _per se_, see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/298025/does-windows-7-have-net-4-installed-by-default) question on superuser.

Comment: oh ! i didn't know that , thank you for the information @TheBlueDog , 
but actually the post says it is offered as an update so it still can get installed without the user going to the microsoft web page and looking for it then downloading it manually :D **thx again**

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it, VS2008 can not target .NET 4.0 that comes with earlier versions of windows it works on .net 3.5 sp1, so i guess i should move to VB2010 to not face any problems running my programs.
*sorry because i maybe didn't know how to ask the question*