# Detect that, at least, a version of .NET Framework is installed

Tags: .net, regedit

Using `regedit` one can easily check the current version of .NET Framework installed on Windows, by looking at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full` and reading the `Release` value.

If your prerequisities are .Net 4.5.2, you can check that `Release` value is the one for 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2. But it doesn't look very safe to me. What if 4.6.3 or 4.7 is released?

Is it fail safe to check that `Release` value is greater than the one for 4.5.2? I can't find anything from Microsoft saying that.

Comment: Just don't check it, let [.NET install an update when required](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034).

Comment: Thank you, but the app is installed by a legacy install shield script and we want the setup to set everything up before the user launches the app.

Comment: Hmm, the point of using an installer builder utility like InstallShield is that you don't have to do this yourself.  Use the company's [help page](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/NetRedistAdd.htm).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx), checking if it's above the required version is safe.

> Backward compatibility means that an app that was developed for a particular version of a platform will run on later versions of that platform. The .NET Framework tries to maximize backward compatibility: Source code written for one version of the .NET Framework should compile on later versions of the .NET Framework, and binaries that run on one version of the .NET Framework should behave identically on later versions of the .NET Framework.