# Check whether .Net Framework 4.6 is installed in system or not

Tags: c#

I have a requirement in my software, in which I need to know whether the client's system have .Net Framework 4.6 installed or not.

What I have tried is -

```
var frameworkVersion = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full", false)?.GetValue("Version");
```

> The above is giving me the highest version installed, that is - 4.7. From which I
>   can't decide whether the client system have framework 4.6 installed
>   specifically.

Comment: Are you asking because you think you can have, say, 4.6.1 installed but not 4.6? If so, each version is an in-place update so 4.6.1 effectively *contains* 4.6.

Comment: If you're asking because you want to check for 4.6 but no further versions, just check for [393295 or 393297](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) specifically.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Are you sure that if one have 4.6.2, then the system will definitely have 4.6 installed? Because, if so, it should solve my issue.

Comment: I am sure, if that helps.

Comment: The user can have only *one* 4.x version installed on his machine.  If you see 4.7 then you know that any code that targets a lesser version, like 4.6, is going to work.  These kind of version checks are not wise btw, simply let [your program update the machine if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034).

Answer (score 2):

This link should give you what you need.
[Dot net installed versions explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#net_d)

To search for a specific version check the number as an equals. They should be backwards compatible, though, so Microsoft recommends checking with greater than the earliest version number you're compatible with.

If you're not forwards compatible..... You might want to fix that.