# How can I configure what .NET version should be installed by windows installer in VS 2017

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

Currently I am working on a project that needs .NET 4.0 to work properly but when I configure the windows installer and try to install it is trying to install the latest version of .NET. So how can I configure the windows installer to install the .NET version on which the project was created. Also I would like to know how to include the Visual C++ Redistributable in my installer.

Comment: .NET 4.0 is too old, you'll need a clean machine that boots XP to get that version installed.  Volunteering to support such an old dog is pretty courageous, formal support ended a long time ago.  Just don't do this, let your app itself ensure that a usable framework version is available.  No help needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a setup project and add primary output of a project to the setup project, the setup project automatically detect dependencies including *Microsoft .Net Framework*. To see if the detected dependency is correctly what you need, you cam see the following locations:

1. First of all, right click on *Dependencies* and click on *Refresh Dependencies*.
2. Check prerequisites for your project:

   - Right click on setup project and choose *Properties*.
   - In Properties dialog, from the *Configurations* combo box choose the configuration, and repeat the following steps for both *Debug* and *Release*.
   - Click on *Prerequisites...* button to open *Prerequisites*.
   - In the *Prerequisites* dialog, check the desired .Net Framework version.
   - Press OK and Make sure you repeat above steps for both *Debug* and *Release*.
3. Check *Launch Conditions* for your setup project:

   - Right click on setup project and from *View* select *Launch Conditions*:
   - Then under *Launch COnditions* node, select *.Net Framework* node and right click and select *Properties Window*.
   - In *Properties Window* check the *Version* property for *.Net Framework* launch condition.

Comment: To include the Visual C++ Run-time libraries, use the *Prerequisites* button described above in the answer.