# Setup project prompting for .NET Framework 4.6.1 when installing

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a solution that contains 4 projects (3 are class libraries build on .NET 4.5.1 and the other is a Windows application also built on 4.5.1. I've added a setup project to the solution and when I build the solution and execute the installer on my Server 2012 r2 I'm getting a message.
The setup requires .NET framework 4.6.1
Why is it needing 4.6.1 when all of my projects are set to 4.5.1?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition 15.6 and the setup project was downloaded from the Marketplace (InstallerProjects.vsix)

Thanks

Comment: Right-click the Setup project > Properties > Prerequisites button.  Untick 4.6.1.  Finding a bootstrapper for 4.5.1 is going to be difficult, support ended over 2 years ago.  Installing an outdated version of the framework is not a great idea.  So maybe you shouldn't fix this at all.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850203/how-can-i-configure-what-net-version-should-be-installed-by-windows-installer-i  where the answer says go to the launch conditions in the setup project and select from the drop dopwn list.

Comment: I've removed the pre-requisites and rebuilt the entire solution but the problem still persits. I've had to resort to a self extracting zip file for now as I can't upgrade the server as part of the install.

Comment: It's nothing to do with prerequisites. The install will ask for the version of the framework in the launch conditions of the setup project.

Comment: Make sure you change the prerequisites for both the Debug and Release configurations. That caused my recent issue.

Comment: I found a way that installer is no longer asking for .NET, however i dont know how to impact application, i just set up in launch conditions that ANY of .NET is required, its not asking for downloading framework anymore