# How do you programatically check the .NET version on both Windows 7 and Windows 10?

Tags: .net, batch-file

I am trying to install an application that requires .NET 4.5.  I need to check if .NET 4.5 is installed or not.  I've created a BAT file to check the .NET version and installer 4.5 (if not already installed) before installing my application.

I'd love to find a BAT script that I can use to check the .NET version, but everything I've found requires another tool that I can't guarantee will be on the installation computer.  Instead, I wrote a small application that checks the .NET version.  The application works fine BUT, I don't know how to get the program to run on all computers.  If I target the application to .NET 2.0, then I run into trouble with computers that have .NET 4.5 but don't have 2.0.  If I target it to run on 4.5, then obviously it requires 4.5 and can only run on computers that already have 4.5.

What is the best way to check if I need to install 4.5, that will work on any configuration of Windows?

Comment: On Windows 10, the answer is "you don't have to". Windows 10 actually came out with 4.6 already installed. 1803 includes 4.7.2. Windows 8 and later had 4.5. Windows 7 is no longer supported. Even so, installers like those created by the [Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) or tools like NSIS or InstallShiled *already* contain actions that check for specific OS, runtime versions

Comment: You do not have to check, just let it [take care of it by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034).

Answer (score 0):

As informed in the comments, there really should be no need to know in advance of running an install, if the installer is anyway half decent, it should stop/inform if the requirements are not met.

Here's a batch file, *(Vista+)*, which should search the registry and list the installed versions nonetheless:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "rk=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
Set/A "vi=ri=0"

For /F "Tokens=3*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%rk%" /F v /K') Do If "%%B"=="" (
    If Not "%%~xA"=="" (Set/A "vi+=1"
        For /F "Tokens=2*" %%C In (
            'Reg Query "%rk%\%%~nxA" /V Version 2^>Nul^|Find /V "\"'
        ) Do Set "_v!vi!=%%D"
    ) Else (Set/A "ri+=1"
        For /F "Tokens=2*" %%E In (
            'Reg Query "%rk%\%%~nxA\Full" /V Release 2^>Nul^|Find /V "\"'
        ) Do Set/A "_r!ri!=%%F"))
If %ri% Gtr 0 (Set/A "vi+=1"
    For /F "Tokens=2" %%A In ('FindStr/B "!_r%ri%!" "%~f0"'
    ) Do Set "_v%vi%=%%A") 

If %vi% Gtr 0 For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set _v') Do Echo([%%B]

Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF

Rem Later Version Table - do not remove
378389 4.5
378675 4.5.1
378758 4.5.1
379893 4.5.2
393295 4.6
393297 4.6
394254 4.6.1
394271 4.6.1
394802 4.6.2
394806 4.6.2
460798 4.7
460805 4.7
461310 4.7.1
461310 4.7.1
```