# Is it possible to start an application with .Net Framework 4.8 on the system with only 4.6 .Net Framework?

Tags: .net, .net-4.8

We've updated our app from 4.6 to 4.8. After some tests I figured out that on the system with only 4.7.1 Framework installed our app starts flawless. However we have no machine with only 4.6 Framework and I have 2 questions:

1. Can the app compiled with 4.8 be started on 4.6 (without any changes in code)?
2. What happens than, if a method available only on 4.8 will be called on the system with lower framework?

Comment: You'll have to test this, eg in a VM

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like a "just don't do that" scenario; if you're targeting a higher platform than exists at runtime, nobody here can guarantee that it will work; might it work by chance? sure... but that doesn't make this a good idea. More recent versions of .NET have self-bundling deployment options, so there is no dependency on a specific runtime being pre-installed (honestly, both net46 and net48 are bad choices for new work without a strong mitigating reason)

Comment: Indeed - why not move to .NET Core/5? You'll have to do this sooner or later, and the self-contained deployment option means you don't need to care about runtimes

Comment: It will start, [eventually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034).  You didn't guess at 4.7.1 correctly, quite hard to find such a machine today.  Windows Update got your back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.6-4.8) details changes between .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.8, so if your project uses anything specified on this guide, the application will throw an exception.

Otherwise, it should work I guess ?