# How to output all .NET framework DLLs used by exe

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, .net-4.7.2

I am using .NET Standard Framework 4.7.2 for a simple console application. Is there a way to output all the necessary referenced dlls from the .NET Framework to the output folder so the user doesn't have to install the .NET Runtime on their machine?

Comment: No, a proper install is a rock-hard requirement.  There are no machines left that don't have it, or can't [automatically update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033128/17034) themselves and run a 4.7.2 program, so nothing to fret about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 4.7.2? Out-of-the box? No.

But you *can* do this with .NET 6.

---

Here's a sample project file that specifies single file publishing:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

---

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)